# I am confused about this error

Tags: python

I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

In my below code:

```
done = False
while not done:
    if You.Hit_points > 0 and Opponent.Hit_points > 0:
        move = raw_input("Would you like to make a move? (y/n) ")
        if move == "y":
            print "",You.name,"hit ",Opponent.name," by",You.Hit_points," hit points!"
            Opponent.Health = You.Hit_points + You.Skill_points + Opponent.Health
```

Thank you!

Comment: Read the error again. Real slow.

Comment: you adding a number to a string, not allowed. Either make all numbers or all strings.

Answer (score 4):

At least one of `Opponent.Health`, `You.Hit_points`, and `You.Skill_points` is a string, and at least of them is a number(an int).  You're trying to add together strings and numbers.  If you intend for all of those values to be numbers, you need to figure out which one isn't and change that.  You could cast all of the values to `int` but that's a short-term solution, this is a problem that will keep coming up if you don't fix it.

All the information you need is in the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

Hit_points is probably an int. Convert it to a string:

```
 str(You.Hit_points)
```

Edit:

Wait, no. Misread, Nolen Royalty is correct. This would probably suffice:

```
Opponent.Health=int(You.Hit_points)+int(You.Skill_points)+int(Opponent.Health)
```

But I would follow Nolen's recommendations.

Comment: He's trying to calculate the opponent's health. That's presumably an integer itself, and not a catenation of three strings.